# Display list of vibration types in Android

Tags: android, notifications, ringtonemanager

I am working on an Android app where in I need to display the vibration types to the user to select similar to what `WhatsApp` does in the Notification settings screen.

Just as the `RingtoneManager` class provides the following `ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER` as seen in below code snippet, do we have a similar `ACTION_VIBRATION_PICKER`. How should I go about implementing the same?

```
 final Intent ringtone = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
ringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
ringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
ringtone.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
        RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
startActivityForResult(ringtone, 0);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think that we have something like `ACTION_VIBRATION_PICKER`. You should implement on your own. You just need to create a dialog like that and then assign a value in milliseconds (duration) for each item in the list.

Comment: @GVillani82: ok. do you have any idea from where Whatsapp gets the list of ringtones?

Comment: They get the ringtones from the media library on your phone, with `ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER`. About the vibration they create a custom dialog (probably a DialogFragment) whit those types of vibration.